# dereferenced unique_ptr and changing values in struct doesn't stick

Tags: c++, c++14, unique-ptr

I'm trying to learn the basics of C++, and like everyone learning pointers is hard.

So, I'm trying out the C++14 `std::unique_ptr` class, and this is probably a silly question.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Foobar {
    bool active = false;   
};

int main()
{
  std::unique_ptr<Foobar> foobar = std::make_unique<Foobar>();

  Foobar foo = *foobar;
  foo.active = true;

  Foobar bar = *foobar;

  // prints zero and not one
  std::cout << bar.active << std::endl;
}
```

Dereferencing my pointer and changing the `bool` in the struct doesn't change the actual underlying value in memory. Why is that so?

What basic thing am I missing?

Comment: `Foobar foo = *foobar` _copies_ the object stored in `foobar` into the local variable `foo`, then `foo.active = true` modifies this local copy. Instead, you'd need to take a reference to it: `Foobar& foo = *foobar` (or you could write `foo->active = true`).

Comment: I typo'd my comment: I meant that you could write `foobar->active = true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Foobar foo = *foobar;
foo.active = true;
```

This makes a copy of the object referenced by `foobar`, and stores it in a new variable called `foo`; then modifies `foo`'s `active` flag.

Of course, this does absolutely nothing to the original object that's (still) referenced by `foobar`.

The code then makes another copy of the object, and prints the unmodified value of its `active` flag.

Comment: Perhaps point out how to make this work (either `foobar->active = true;` or `Foobar& foo = *foobar; foo.active = true;`)?